# Sequência Fibonacci

Tags: php, fibonnaci

Preciso realizar um exercício para mostrar a sequência Fibonacci até o 100º elemento, devo criar uma função Fibonacci que deverá receber o índice do elemento e a função irá calcular o número correspondente daquele índice.

Atualmente estou realizando assim, porem gostaria de saber onde estou errando?

segue o código:

```
$sequence = array();

for ($i=1; $i <= 100 ; $i++) { 
    if ($i < 2) {
        $sequence[$i] = $i;         
    } else{
        $sequence[$i] = $sequence[$i - 1] + $sequence[$i - 2];          
    }       
}

function fibonacci($n){

    echo $sequence[$n];

};

fibonacci(100);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Um problema que eu encontrei foi seu IF não pular os 2 primeiros números, veja a sutil diferença:

```
$sequence = array();

for ( $i = 1; $i <= 100 ; $i++) { 
    if ($i <= 2) { // Ou começa $i de 0, ou usa "<=" aqui em vez do "<"
        $sequence[$i] = $i;         
    } else{
        $sequence[$i] = $sequence[$i - 1] + $sequence[$i - 2];          
    }       
}

function fibonacci($n){
    global $sequence;
    echo $sequence[$n];

};

fibonacci(100);
```

Além disso, acrescentei esta linha:

```
global $sequence;
```

pois, dentro de uma função, o escopo é diferente. Sem o `global`, o `$sequence` que você está tentando exibir dentro da função é uma nova variável, e não a mesma setada fora.

Talvez fosse melhor desta forma, começando de zero, pois na opção acima, estamos com *offset* de 1 na fórmula:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100 ; $i++) { 
   if ( $i < 2 ) {
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hf4RKQ)**.

### Uma alternativa mais enxuta

Uma maneira seria simplificar o código e calcular os números só na chamada. O uso de *array* pré-calculado só faz sentido se você sabe que vai precisar de vários valores:

```
function fibonacci($n) {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    $c = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
        $c = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $c;
    }
    return $c;
}
echo fibonacci(100) ."\n";
```

A desvantagem dessa é que a cada vez que você precisa de um número, está refazendo o cálculo todo. A vantagem é que se for um número grande, vai gastar tempo, mas nao precisa armazenar na memória (claro que com números grandes vai começar a ter problemas de desvio e até *overflow*, em qualquer uma das funções)

Veja esta versão no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/w5Tap2)**.

### Fórmula Matemática

Como se trata de um exercício, a solução ideal é o loop acima, e para o cálculo de vários números, o loop com soma é mais simples para a máquina processar. Mas se algum leitor chegou aqui precisando calcular algum dos números da série, tem um jeito "direto" de se chegar no resultado:

[image: Fn = [ Phi n - (phi)n ]/Sqrt[5]]

Ou seja, F<sub>n</sub> = [ Phi<sup>n</sup> - (phi)<sup>n</sup> ] / Sqrt(5), sendo que Phi é `(1+Sqrt(5))/2`, e phi é `-1/Phi`, podemos fazer isto:

```
function fibonacci( $n ) {
   $V5   = sqrt( 5 );
   $Phi  = ( 1 + $V5 ) / 2;
   $iPhi = -1 / $Phi;
   return round( ( pow( $Phi, $n ) - pow( $iPhi, $n ) ) / $V5 );
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/epYP51)**.

Leia mais na Wikipedia sobre:

- [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) (atualmente o conteúdo em inglês está melhor).
- [Proporção áurea](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%C3%A1urea)

Comment: Para quem for usar a fórmula com φ e Φ: Só para lembrar haverá problema de precisão usando ponto flutuante, já que raiz de 5 não é representável em uma quantidade finitas de casas binárias. Esse problema só deve acontecer quando `n` for suficientemente grande. E, outro ponto divertido, a resolução analítica dessa potenciação sempre ocasiona na anulação de **todos** os fatores de raiz de 5 que não estejam elevados a número par, então a resposta **sempre** é inteira

Answer (score 1):

```
function fibonacci($numero_limite):array
{
    $matriz = [0,1];

    for($i=1;$i<$numero_limite;$i++)
    {
        array_push($matriz, $matriz[$i]+$matriz[$i-1]);
    }
    return $matriz;
}
```

//Exemplo de uso;

```
print_r(fibonacci(10));
```

//Retorno

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 5 [6] => 8 [7] => 13 [8] => 21 [9] => 34 [10] => 55 )
```