# Escreva um código em PHP em que você imprima na tela os 10 primeiros termos da sequência de Fibonacci a partir dos termos 89 e 144

Tags: php, fibonnaci

1. Meu rascunho esta assim no momento, entretanto todas as tentativas de por um while não funcionaram.

```
<?php
$n=$_GET['number'];
$ultimo = 1;
$penúltimo=0;

echo "0<br />1<br />";
for($count=1; $count<= $n-2 ; $count++){
$atual = $ultimo + $penultimo;
echo $atual. "br<br />;

$penúltimo = $ultimo;
$ultimo = $atual;
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Sequência Fibonacci](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103913/sequ%c3%aancia-fibonacci)

Answer (score -2):

Se você deseja utilizar um laço de repetição "while" para imprimir os números da sequência de Fibonacci, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
$n = $_GET['number'];
$ultimo = 1;
$penultimo = 0;
echo "0<br />1<br />";
$count = 1;
while ($count <= $n-2) {
    $atual = $ultimo + $penultimo;
    echo $atual . "<br />";
    $penultimo = $ultimo;
    $ultimo = $atual;
    $count++;
}
?>
```

A variável $count é iniciada com 1 e é incrementada a cada iteração do loop, enquanto o loop continuará executando enquanto $count for menor ou igual a $n-2.

Dentro do loop, você calcula o próximo número na sequência de Fibonacci somando o último e o penúltimo números. Depois você imprime o valor calculado, atualiza o penúltimo e o último números para se preparar para o próximo cálculo.

Além disso, verifique se não há nenhum erro de sintaxe, como as aspas duplas no echo e a vírgula para separar os elementos, que deveria ser um ponto.